# Do exists a software like FTPBox for Mac ?

Tags: sync, ftp

i need a software like FTPBox for Mac, who is a client FTP which monitor a local folder and keep synced with a remote ftp folder. It works like Dropbox but you can 'host' the service on your server.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular FTP Client programs out there, [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/), recently launched the Mac version of their program. From my use with both versions, the Mac version appears to work just as good as the PC version.

I have used it to automatically sync before. You have to change some additional settings, but it is possible. I think this does the job you're looking for.

[automatic folder subtree file synchronization](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/1591)

[how to synchronize with FileZilla](http://www.ehow.com/how_8396727_sync-files-filezilla.html)

Give that a shot.

Comment: Does it do what the OP wants?

Comment: I believe so, I have used it to automatically sync before. I will attach some links to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [iFolder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ifolder/) will do the trick.